# C# - Loading Shapes into PictureBox from a text file with data describing each shape

Tags: c#, string, list, file

I have perfectly working code to load & save shapes from a text file that contains the type of the shape (i use an enum called shapetype), the x1,y1 (initial mouse down location) coords and the x2,y2 (final location of mouse cursor once mouse was dragged somewhere and the left button was released). The data also stores the color of the shape as a rgb int and a true/false value for if the shape is to be filled in a solid or just an outline.

The only thing I am asking is how i could have the exact same thing but ***all the data for 1 shape on one line in my text file* and still be able to load it up.** I know how to SAVE the data on one line but i do not know how i would load the data if everything was on one line for each shape...

The code right now is:

```
   private void loadCanvas(List<APShape> shapeList)
        {
            shapeList.Clear();
            string line = "";
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            open.Filter = "Shape Data Files | *.shapes";
            if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Stream s = File.Open(open.FileName, FileMode.Open);
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
                while (line != null)
                {
                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (line != null)
                    {
                        shapeList.Add(ObjectFromTxt(line));
                        shapeList[shapeList.Count - 1].setColor(Color.FromArgb(int.Parse(sr.ReadLine())));
                        shapeList[shapeList.Count - 1].setX1(int.Parse(sr.ReadLine()));
                        shapeList[shapeList.Count - 1].setY1(int.Parse(sr.ReadLine()));
                        shapeList[shapeList.Count - 1].setX2(int.Parse(sr.ReadLine()));
                        shapeList[shapeList.Count - 1].setY2(int.Parse(sr.ReadLine()));
                        shapeList[shapeList.Count - 1].setSolid(string2bool(sr.ReadLine()));
                        shapeList[shapeList.Count - 1].setPenWidth(float.Parse(sr.ReadLine()));

                    }
                }
                sr.Close();
                canvas.Invalidate();
            }
        }
```

And how the file with the text holding the shape data looks is:
[Current file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6N2c.png)

Comment: You should research *serialization*

Comment: Do you mean you want to know how to split data from one line into an array? `string.Split(sepl)`does that. Just make sure to have a separator not used in the data. But: for much more robust storage&retrieval you may want to consider key-value pairs, which is just a tiny step from full-scalel serializaton.

Comment: I can split the data into an array however im not sure where I would go from there to load that into my List of APSHAPE objects

Comment: you would use the index of the array to pull out the item.  If you write all items in the line the same then each index of your array would reference that item. so first item in the array is your RGB color, second item is x1 and so on.  The  right answer is what New Contributor stated.  Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/

Comment: I have used the wonderful newtonsoft json library and successfully using serialization to achieve this task. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

End Result

```
  private void saveCanvas()
        {
            SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
            save.DefaultExt = ".shapes";
            save.Filter = "Shapes File (*.shapes) |*.shapes";

            if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                File.Delete(save.FileName);
                var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };
                File.WriteAllText(save.FileName, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(shapes, shapes.GetType(), settings));
            }
        }


        private void loadCanvas()
        {
            List<APShape> shapeList = new List<APShape>();
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            open.Filter = "Shapes File (*.shapes) |*.shapes";

            if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                shapes.Clear();       /* Clear canvas to make sure we are starting blank */
                canvas.Invalidate();

                var json = File.ReadAllText(open.FileName);
                var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };

                shapeList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<APShape>>(json, settings);

                foreach (var shape in shapeList)
                {
                    shapes.Add(shape);
                }
                canvas.Invalidate();      
            }
    }
```